# Can I prevent keyboard repeat for certain keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, accessibility, repeat-rate

Sometimes I accidentally put my arm on the `Numpad Enter` when coding and when the enter key starts repeating, things get messy. I use `Windows 7` on a desktop computer and my keyboard is a DELL standard USB keyboard. I want to know if I can disable keyboard repeat ***just for the*** `Numpad Enter` key.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You can change it for all keys, as the answer provides, but not for a single key. Maybe a better approach is to buy a rubber band and put it around your wrist. Every time you hit that button, you pull it and release it. Yes, that is supposed to hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *Accessibilty Options* in the *Control Panel* in order to achieve that.

1. Go to *Start*, *Control Panel*.
2. Choose *Accessibility Options*. (Depending on your Control Panel
   view, you may need to choose *Accessibility Options* again at the
   next screen listing *Tasks* or you may go directly to *Options*
   settings below.)
3. On the *Keyboard* tab, check "Filter Keys" and click "Settings"
   button.
4. Select "Ignore Quick Keystrokes" and click "Settings"
   button.
5. Select "No Repeat ..." at the bottom of the box, adjust the "Keys
   Must Be Held ..." time to 0.0 (so the key will still type as soon as
   you hit it.)

Comment: BTW, this is a global solution. There is no other methods for predefined keys that I know of...

Comment: Currently in Windows 10 this is called 'Sticky Keys'